# We have a new community called "Interpersonal Skills"

Tags: discussion

In my 4 years on ELU, I've sometimes come across questions seeking advice on how to respond to someone in certain situations, and such off-topic questions are closed and deleted, however, in the meantime, I've seen many users helping out the OP in the comments.

Now we have a brand new Stack Exchange community dedicated to helping people on such matters involving interpersonal skills. It should cover topics such as "is it rude to say x to y?", "how to respond to x when I'm in y?", etc.

From now on, when we close such off-topic questions, please direct the OP to [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) and it will help them a lot.

The topics allowed there are not yet clearly defined, and I hope that some of our ELU users can help the new community grow, so please do visit.

Comment: follow up question: do you think a migration link should be set up once it comes out of beta?

Comment: @marcellothearcane it could take years before it becomes a fully fledged site. ELL waited three years (more or less) to leave beta. Baby steps.. baby steps

Comment: @marcellothearcane What MariLouA said. And the waiting period can be reduced only if somehow miraculously the site becomes populated with too many daily users and posts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and NVZ okay, thanks for the info :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I have been meaning to, but you beat me to it haha.

Comment: Are those *Is it rude to do such and such?* questions actually on topic on that site? For instance: is it rude to use a person's driveway to turn around? How are they not opinion based? Rude is not the same as illegal.  (As  a matter of fact, trespassing is not illegal in many (rural) places.) Or are opinion based questions fine over there? And I'm not asking over there because I don't want to join that site.

Comment: @Clare Not all stack exchange sites are looking for facts. Some need expert opinions. There's an article "good subjective, bad subjective" somewhere on Stack Exchange blogs.

Comment: @Clare There's a site, yes. But what's on topic and what's not is up for discussion. Show up there, and provide your input on where we should draw the line. The site is still in beta phase. Now is the time to shape it to our needs.

Comment: Expert opinions on what constitutes rudeness?

Comment: @Clare come on now. This comment section is not the place for your queries. Come over to ips meta if your questions are sincere. I won't be answering your questions here.

Comment: @Clare https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38852189#38852189 _Welcome to Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange, new users! Our site is a bit peculiar, in that it deals with some pretty subjective topics, and we know that. We still have some problems to solve, and we'd love your help. If you have any questions please ask them here in chat; we'd also like to hear your voices on meta. I hope to see you around on the main site._

Comment: I don't believe Clare's example to be pertinent for the site. What "skill" or act of diplomacy is involved in using someone else's driveway? One could ask "How should I reply if someone accuses me of using their driveway inappropriately?" I would imagine that type of question is answerable albeit based on one's personal experience.

Comment: @clare Such questions should be scoped to a particular culture, and answers should present the culture's general view and not an individual's view.

Comment: I browsed the site, and saw a lot of familiar users.

Comment: I asked a question and got some valuable answers.

Comment: would this question be a good example? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181651/how-do-we-refer-to-body-odour-delicately If, for example,  WS2 was willing to post his question there, what would he have to do? Could he ask the same question without having to migrate the original? It would be too old to migrate, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA My opinion would be just mine. Would you like to hear the opinions of other senior users of IPS?

Comment: no, your opinion is the one I'm interested in the most :) This is purely hypothetical. I was just wondering what would I have to do if I was in a similar situation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA WS2 is asking for "a term to use" and "appropriate language". I think "appropriate language" is something IPS can help with. "a term to use" falls under ELU's scope. Migration is not possible. Re-asking, but after rewording it to better fit IPS would make it a good question there. Or maybe even for [workplace.se].

Comment: Good advice and tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you all an idea of what kind of questions could be migrated from ELU to IPS, here are some recent ones which have the right subject matters (but may not be specific enough to be migrated to IPS):

- [What do you say when you want to look around in a store and don't need help?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399844/59258)
- [What is an appropriate greeting for the US Memorial Day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391376/59258)
- [How to informally inform about upcoming vacation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/387850/59258)

Comment: Nice find. So would you like to migrate those now?

Comment: @NVZ I've already written custom flags for them.

Comment: Interim mods at IPS have requested that questions are not migrated at present, but that querents are directed to that site to ask a question which is site-specific. None of the suggested questions here are really *interpersonal skills* (not that they are really on-topic here either: sometimes there isn't a Stack Exchange site and Yahoo! Answers really is the best place).

Comment: @AndrewLeach you mean community managers or moderator nominees?

Comment: I mean interim moderators: users who are currently fulfilling the moderator role.